# How to see the schema of a db2 table (file)

Tags: file, db2, schema

As in subject... is there a way of looking at an empty table schema without inserting any rows and issuing a SELECT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for [DESCRIBE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0002019.htm)?

`db2 describe table user1.department`

```
Table: USER1.DEPARTMENT

Column             Type        Type
name               schema      name               Length   Scale    Nulls
------------------ ----------- ------------------ -------- -------- --------
AREA               SYSIBM      SMALLINT                  2        0 No
DEPT               SYSIBM      CHARACTER                 3        0 No
DEPTNAME           SYSIBM      CHARACTER                20        0 Yes
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT *                
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS  
WHERE                   
TBNAME    = 'tablename';
```

Answer (score 8):

For DB2 AS/400 (V5R4 here) I used the following queries to examine for database / table / column metadata:

SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.TABLES -- Provides all tables

SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.VIEWS -- Provides all views and their source (!!) definition

SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS -- Provides all columns, their data types & sizes, default values, etc.

SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SQLPRIMARYKEYS -- Provides a list of primary keys and their order

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153920/php-unixodbc-db2-describe-token-not-valid), DESCRIBE may not work. I believe there is a system table that stores all of the field information.

Perhaps [this will help you out](http://www.code400.com/ffd.php). A bit more coding but far more accurate.