# how to set schema in ado.net after open the connection

Tags: ado.net

I am connecting to the db2 database in this database different schemas are there.
 I want to connect to connect particular schema only, 
I tried that in connection string we cant give the schema, 
After connection opening only we have to set the schema, 
I have a code that i.e by using connect to the active data object(ADO) only, 
but in ado.net how to give i dont know 
Below is the code for ado connection

```
db.Open DBcon_string 
db.Execute ("SET SCHEMA=" & AppSchema) 
db.Execute ("SET PATH=""SYSIBM"",""SYSFUN"",""SYSPROC"",""SYSIBMADM"",""" & AppSchema & """")
```

Note: db is adodb.connection 
Replace AppSchema with ‘ETWRMS’

Comment: Please look to the below post and the code, it may help!

Answer (score 0):

The below Link may prove to be helpful-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link "Using an ADO.NET Entity Framework Data Provider"

http://www.datadirect.com/download/eval_docs/dotnet_win_quickstart.htm

Similar kinda issue taht may help-

[How to see the schema of a db2 table (file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153769/how-to-see-the-schema-of-a-db2-table-file)

Answer (score 0):

It would be similar in ADO.NET. Assuming you're using OleDbConnection - create and open it. Then create an OleDbCommand using that connection. Then using command's `ExecuteNonQuery` method issue same statements you did using old "db.Execute" method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try-

```
db.Open DBcon_string 

db.ExecuteNonQuery ("SET SCHEMA=" & AppSchema) 

db.ExecuteNonQuery ("SET PATH=""SYSIBM"",""SYSFUN"",""SYSPROC"",""SYSIBMADM"",""" & AppSchema & """")
```